# Update a second table, using trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to create a simple trigger, but, i can't set the **media** value on **prato** if the value comes from **@total** or **@sum**.
I've already tested to substitute them for "1" or "1+1", to see if i wasn't even updating correctly or the problem was the operation itself.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER ratings_prato BEFORE INSERT ON ratings
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        SET @total = @total + 1;
        SET @sum = NEW.stars + @sum;
        UPDATE prato p SET p.media = @sum/@total WHERE p.id = 1;
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Any ideias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've completed mislead the `FOR EACH ROW` on *trigger*. I thought, every time it was updated, It would run trough all rows. But, instead of it, it executes for each row it was **updated**, which, make things possible.

This was the last result of my trigger, inserting on ratings, and updating on food(which was *prato*)

```
DELIMITER $$  
CREATE
  TRIGGER inserting_dishes_rating AFTER INSERT ON ratings  
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    IF(NEW.food_id is not null) THEN  
      SET @media = (SELECT SUM(stars) FROM ratings WHERE food_id = NEW.food_id) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ratings WHERE food_id = NEW.food_id);
      UPDATE foods f SET f.rate = @media WHERE f.id = NEW.food_id;
    ELSE
      SET @media = (SELECT SUM(stars) FROM ratings WHERE restaurant_id = NEW.restaurant_id) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ratings WHERE restaurant_id = NEW.restaurant_id);  
      UPDATE restaurants r SET r.rate = @media WHERE r.id = NEW.restaurant_id;
    END IF;
END
```